# MongoDB profiling level automatically reverts to zero

Tags: mongodb

I've got a non-sharded MMAPv1 replica set running in the MongoDB Cloud Manager. I want to keep profiling on indefinitely for several databases, but for some reason it returns to zero after maybe 48 hours or so.

Is there something in the MongoDB database server or perhaps the Cloud Manager that sets the profiling level to zero? I don't see anything in my code that would do this, and noone with access to the databases is manually changing the profiling level.

I enabled profiling for each database by executing `db.setProfilingLevel(1)` from the `mongo` console. Result:

```
{
  "was": 0,
  "slowms": 100,
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: This is a bit off-topic for StackOverflow and should be asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). I take it you are setting the profiling level from  shell connection?

Comment: I'm fine with moving to dba.stackexchange.com if that's the consensus. I called `setProfilingLevel(1)` from the `mongo` console to enable profiling. I'll add info about this to the question.

Comment: It's generally the consensus to have the DBA topics on that site as it is about DBA things like configuration and StackOverflow is for programming things. It generally is not recommended to leave profiling on as it can have a significant impact. But possibly the `--profile` option or `operationProfiling` in config might be more persistent.

Answer (score 0):

When using the *db.setProfilingLevel(1)* command, if mongod is restarted (perhaps by MongoDB Cloud Manager if you are using it), it resets profiling level to default (0).

To keep the expected profiling level after reboot, you can use option [operationProfiling.mode](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#operationProfiling.mode) in your mongod config file.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the MongoDB Cloud Manager. Ah, good call. I haven't noticed any EC2 instance reboots, but maybe the Cloud Manager restarts `mongod` after updating "automation", "backup" or "monitoring" agents (something I do regularly).